# How to calculate percentage from two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

please, help me calculate percentage of number of clients from two tables, which made payments during 01.01.2018 - 05.01.2018.

```
clients

client_id  sum     date
100      2400   01.01.2018
101      2550   02.01.2018
120      2345   05.01.2018
155      5526   30.03.2018
```

the second table

```
payments 

client_id   total  date
100        47    01.01.2018
101        50    02.01.2018
120        0    05.01.2018
155        20    30.03.2018
```

I write such query, but it does not work correctly:

```
SELECT (COUNT(distinct payments.client_id) / (COUNT(distinct 
clients.client_id)) * 100) AS percent, payments.date 
FROM payments, clients WHERE
payments.date between '2018-01-01' 
and '2018-01-05' 
GROUP BY
(payments.date);
```

Thanks!

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: this appears to have nothing to do with jquery. Don't add tags just because it's part of your whole application. Only add them if they're actually relevant to the code in the question. Thanks. At the time of writing there is an edit pending which will remove the tag.

Comment: Welcome to SO. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

use join and i think you want to calculate total payment percentage according to date

```
SELECT p.date ,
( sum(p.total) /sum(c.sum)) * 100.00) AS percent
FROM payments p join  clients  c on p.client_id=c.client_id
WHERE
p.date between '2018-01-01' 
and '2018-01-05' 
GROUP BY
p.date
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

To count the ration of payments vs clients. I did not see how this could be done using a JOIN.

```
SELECT 100 * COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) / (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                     FROM clients 
                                     WHERE date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-31') as 'Percent' 
FROM Payments p
WHERE p.date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-31'
```

---

Calculate sum for each table Join the two tables on client_id and date

```
SELECT 100 * SUM(p.total) / SUM(c.sum) as 'Percent'
FROM Payments p
JOIN clients c ON p.client_id = c.client_id AND p.date = c.date
WHERE p.date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-05'
```

Percent
2.1933

Add GROUP BY if you want per date

```
SELECT p.date as 'Date', 100 * SUM(p.total) / SUM(c.sum) as 'Percent'
FROM Payments p
JOIN clients c ON p.client_id = c.client_id AND p.date = c.date
WHERE p.date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-05' 
GROUP BY p.date
```

**Date Percent**
2018-01-01  1.9583
2018-01-02  1.9608
2018-01-05  2.6866

Comment: Thanks) Is there a possibility to do it in one query and using COUNT (DISTINCT) ? Because I need sum of unique id

Comment: Sorry but I don’t understand. I showed to queries because I was unsure which result you wanted and what do you mean with “sum of unique id” and using Count instead of Sum?

Comment: Maybe I was wrong, I need to calculate percent of clients that made payments in certain date. In this case 100%.
But if someone do not pay - this percent will be lower.

How it is bettr to do this?